# Unable to set background color with Absolute and Fixed positions

Tags: html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm unable to set background color when i use position to my signin div and bottom div.I tried to remove position but it didn't give the expected outcome. I cannot use `body {background-color: red}` because my interfaces have different colors. What should i do?
Thanks

This is my code

```
<div className="abc">
  <Grid doubling stackable className="mainGrid">
    <div className="SignInDiv">
      <Grid.Row className="titleRowSI">sign in</Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Row className="inputSpaceSI">
        <Input className="inputStyle" type="text" placeholder="User Name" />
      </Grid.Row>
      .
      .
      .

      <Grid.Row className="inputSpaceSI" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
        Don't Have a Account ?
        <a className="linkStyle" href="/account">
          Create Account
        </a>
      </Grid.Row>
    </div>
    <div className="bottomDivSI">
      <a className="linkStyle" href="#">
        Privacy Policy
      </a>
      <a className="linkStyle" href="#">
        Terms & Conditions
      </a>
      <a className="linkStyle" href="#">
        Copyright
      </a>
    </div>
  </Grid>
</div>
```

this is my css file

```
.abc{
    background-color: tomato !important;
}

.mainGrid{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.SignInDiv{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    /* background-color: #B75D69; */
}

.bottomDivSI{
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 3rem !important;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You're apparently using some kind of framework (React, perhaps?) because your HTML is invalid (`className` should be `class`, there's no such tag as `Grid` or `Grid.Row`, etc.). Please [edit] your question to include the tags for that framework/library.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

When you set div with the class `SignInDiv`  which contains a css attribute of `position: absolute` you are essentially removing it from parent/child hierarchy.

As a result your div element with the class `abc` is no longer inheriting the height of that div. As a result it has a height of `0px`.

To combat this, you need to hard code your height of this div. Simply amend your css to include the following:

## Solution

```
.abc {
    background-color: tomato !important;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: You are very welcome. Please mark this question as answered.